# Spring Security with Spring Boot and OAuth 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have seen some tutorials

where some of them do the configuration in yml for OAuth as below

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
```

Some example do it as

```
   spring:
    security:
      oauth2:
        client:
```

What is the difference between these.

any book or blog or doc where i can learn spring security indepth specially Oauth and SSO

Comment: this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angular) is explaining about spring security and OAuth2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first configuration is what you would use if you're using Spring Boot and the Spring Security Oauth project (now in maintenance mode). You can find a simple Spring guide [here](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html).

The second you'd use if you're using Spring Boot with the new Spring Security 5 (which is replacing Spring Security Oauth project).

Since Spring Security 5 is where things will be happening, I'd recommend you start by taking a look at the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle).